# I can't use the cell content and do formulas with it

Tags: excel, function, currency-exchange-rates

Currently I've made an excel document where it gets it data from a website with the help of "Data - From Web".

I've gotten this part to work, however i need to use the cell-content in some of the cells to do calculations, but it appears that these are not values (i believe they are text-strings?!)

Some searching gave me the tip to use the =Value() function but this seems not to work as intended (see picture).

I need help to make sure that my table is usable.

**Sidenote**, I have a feeling that the decimal indicator is an dot "." however my excel uses a comma ","

Your help/assistance is much appreciated!

[image: eb]

Comment: A link to the site where I'm getting my Currency-rates.


https://www.dnb.se/se/sv/markets/valuta-rentor/kurslista/overforing/daglig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the download is using `dot` as the decimal separator and your Windows Regional Settings are using something else. If that suspicion is correct, when you set up the query (or Edit the current query)

- select `Transform` instead of `Load` *(or edit the current query)*
- Select the numeric columns
- From the right-click menu on one of the columns, select `Change Type -> Using Locale` and select `Decimal Number`  from `English(United States)`

That should enable the values to be converted to numeric values you can use.  And that should maintain whenever you update the query.

Comment: You got it to work man, many thanks.
Because it seems you know these kind of things, could you help me with another one. I would like to change the format of Column A to YYYY-MMYDD (i.e 2019-12-12).

I would like to have it so that you can easily filter the dates.

https://gyazo.com/eeb51d0e6179de947745c83d50687ab7

Comment: @SwE3xHD The format of a date should not affect your ability to filter. Post this as a new question, and outline what you have done to overcome your problem, and where you have run into problems. To help you provide sufficient information, please take a look at the Help topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)